# Facebook iOS sdk 3.10 share local image or movie

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I used Facebook sdk in the past, but the new version is making me crazy. I'm trying to create a `UIActivity` subclass that calls the official facebook share dialog. Since for someone having the "via iOS" instead of the app name in the post is a first world problem (just kidding), I can't use the iOS native integration with the `SLComposeViewController`. 
In the documentation it seems that for post a picture using the share dialogs you need to use open graph actions, but is not totally clear to me if you can do inside your app, or you need to rely on external php application. 
I've seen that there are some common actions that wouldn't require a declaration of a new one, but posting a photo or a movie it doesn't seems to be there.
I'd like to use something "native" as a share dialog instead of an `FBSession` if possible.

Comment: You can post a photo using open graph actions and the object api (no server to host). Have a look at the Scrumptious sample app, which shows you how to use both the native share dialog to share an open graph action, as well as just POSTing an open graph action if you already have the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thanks Ming, but actually in the scrumptious example the do set up custom actions hosted on a server https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios-sdk-tutorial/publish-open-graph-story/ using a share dialog. For the FBRequest I do know about "just posting". The OP is about post image/video using native dialogs, if possible, or using other means but with a share dialog as well.

Comment: The Scrumptious example does both. It uses server hosted objects if you pick one of the existing menu items, but will also use the Object API if you pick "Write your Own" from the menu option.